# How to call Python back-end from Flutter

Tags: python, flutter

Is there any way for me to link a python back-end function to a flutter mobile application? I have a face recognition method on Python that needs to be linked to my front-end Flutter app.

It must also work offline

Comment: Create a REST api for the face recognition with django and call the service with http library in flutter.

Comment: The face recognition method has to also work offline

Comment: TensorFlow Lite for mobile maybe.

Comment: Interesting, might give it a try, thanks